# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.HtmlString' in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, compiler-errors

I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.HtmlString' when I attempt to assign a value to a variable of type htmlstring, the value is being read from an xml file (code snippet below)

The convert method does not have a built in conversion from string to htmlstring. There is a method ToHtmlString but not sure how to use it in this situation as it is not available with a string object. Your suggestions please.

```
public class Xclass
{
    public HtmlString content { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }    
}

Xclass x = (from c in xdoc.Descendants("div") select new Xclass()
{
    content = c.Value, //c.value is the html content of div, content is a property of   type HtmlString 
    id = c.id
});
```

Comment: You have a `string`. It wants a [`HtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring.aspx) so, how can you get from one to the other? And what issues may there be? (Hint: it won't be encoded again, which could be...)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

can you not do `content =new HtmlString(c.Value);`
?

Comment: Thanks Sachin for your super quick response, that did indeed fix that error!

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/p/1755956/4765315.aspx/1?Help+Cannot+implicitly+convert+type+string+to+System+Web+HtmlString+

Comment: Also you can do that in short like this: `@"" + c.Value`

Comment: [MvcHtmlString.Create(String)]

Answer (score 3):

Try using 
`MvcHtmlString.Create(String)` Method

If you are using the MVC 5.2 or later.